# Diferencias en fechas power apps > power automate > sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps

Estoy enviando un campo tipo fecha a un flujo de power automate pero al insertarla en un registro de una lista de sharepoint la hora cambia:

*Cambia la hora, los minutos se mantienen

[image: Muestra hora local 15:50]

Esto llegó a Sharepoint

[image: Muestra hora creación elemento en Sharepoint 7:50]